# Dynamically modify the url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, browser

I would like to change the url of the page when the user select another page to visit. The url is dynamically replace the original one.

eg.

If user visit page 1 , the url will be `book.html?page=1`

If page 30 then `book.html?page=30` and so on.

However, when I change the link using javascript, it falls into a infinite loop.

It seems I keep visit->change link ->visit ->change link->.... How to fix this problem?

eg. When the link change, don't access the page.

```
var currURL = $(location).attr('href');
var index = currURL.indexOf('?');
currURL = currURL.substring(0, index != -1 ? index : currURL.length);
// fall into loop
$(location).attr('href', currURL + '?page=' + pageNo);
```

Comment: Issues in your ternary operator I think, what are the values you get in `currURL.length`

Comment: This is because when you change `location.href` it will reload the whole page and run your code again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with just standard javascript.

```
if(location.href.indexOf('?') !== -1 && location.href.indexof('?page=') === -1)
{
    var urlArray = location.href.split('?');
    var newURL = urlArray[0] + "?page=" + urlArray[1];
    location.href = newURL;
}
```